# How to use views to display a list of views pages?

Tags: views

I currently have a view that outputs all the current nodes on a site in a table format to display things like:

- Title
- Nid
- Path
- Metatag Title
- Metatag Description
- Metatag Keywords
- Post Date
- Updated Date
- and an edit link.

We mainly use this view to review our SEO optimisation in terms of the meta tags and the path constructions for each "page" on the site.

It's a nice system, but it has one major failing - it does not include any views pages - things like event listings or news listing pages. These views pages are just as important for SEO optimisation but I cannot get them to be included in this review list.

The metatag information is provided by the D7 Metatag module. With that module, we can add tag information to views pages, which is great, but to complete this admin view, it would be good to be able to include the views pages on the site in the above list as well.

It would be fine for this to be displayed in a standalone output (ie not included in the full table page above) but I cannot for the life of me find a way to get this done.

Is there any way to create a view that will list all view pages on a site with their associated meta information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is not possible. De data that the views stores is not provided back to the views module. As you've noticed, you're not able to create a list of views using a view.

I can think of two options to make this possible:

- Create a (complete) custom module that selects and outputs the values you desire
- or, provide the views module with the data you need to create the list you want

Both options require custom code to make it possible. At this moment, both views and metatags don't allow you to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment! I was afraid on that! Would you be able to provide any guidance on your two suggestions above? Am a bit of a noob when it comes to working with views in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way to list views pages in a view. What I do as a workaround, though, is to create a content type called something like "Interface Element" and give it text and image fields and create nodes with direct links to the views pages. Then I can create a view that lists those nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [Views Field View Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view). You might have to drill down some tutorial on the web.